# Adding Output Values to a CSV file Using a Loop

Tags: loops, julia, export-to-csv

I'm trying to use the for loop to make a calculation over a sequence of values. When this loop ends, I want to get a single csv file with four rows, each row for each iteration.

```
DD00 = readcsv(".../Output/y=0.0.csv")
DD0  = DD00[1,:]

for x in linspace(0.,π,4)
    DD = readcsv(".../Output/y=$(x/π).csv")
    writecsv(".../Output/DDD.csv", transpose(hcat(DD0,DD[1,:])))
end
```

What I'm getting is a csv file with only two rows. The first row is the results of the initial value (`0.`) and a second row which is the results of the final value (`π`) in `linspace`! I would expect a csv file with four rows, each row for each iteration. I think the problem is that Julia is overwriting the file in each loop so we get a file with the result of the last iteration only. Thanks so much for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a technical reason for using an old version of julia (linspace is now deprecated) and no packages, maybe try

```
temp = []
for x in linspace(0.,π,4)
    DD = readcsv(".../Output/y=$(x/π).csv")
    temp = vcat(temp, DD[1,:])
end
writecsv(".../Output/DDD.csv", temp)
```

Otherwise I'd suggest using the latest version of julia and the packages CSV and DataFrames - where you could try something like this

```
import Pkg
Pkg.add("DataFrames")
Pkg.add("CSV") # to install packages

import DataFrames
import CSV

temp = DataFrames.DataFrame()
for x in range(0., stop = π, length = 4)
    DD = CSV.read(".../Output/y=$(x/π).csv") |> DataFrames.DataFrame
    append!(temp, DataFrames.DataFrame( DD[1,:] ) )
end

CSV.write(".../Output/DDD.csv", temp)
```